# RSJX Observable not returning data

Tags: group-by, rxjs, observable

The following code, when subscribed to, returns an expected array of objects.

```
this.store.select (this.selectors.evidenceSelector);
```

The objects include a 'subjectId' field.
This code, based on multiple examples on the web, returns nothing when subscribed to:

```
this.store
      .select (this.selectors.evidenceSelector)
      .pipe (
        groupBy (ev => ev['subjectId']),
        mergeMap (group$ => group$.pipe(toArray())),
      );
```

The subscription never gets triggered...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you place the tap operator between groupBy and mergeMap and see if some output comes?

Comment: Can you make a minimal repro on stackblitz? Just replace your store select with a `from` and emits a few values that looks like what you want

Comment: Are you sure you have subscribed to the stream? I dont see any subscription at the code you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh after reading again... I think I've figured out what's going on here.

`toArray` will only emit a value when the stream is closed. As you're listening from your store (which will never be closed), you'll never get anything under the `toArray`. You have to use something like scan if you want to accumulate and show a result on every new emission.

Comment: I may have been too "generous" in using an observable here, I just need to know that the results are from the group bay are at a point in time. What's easiest way to do that since my stores as you say will never close their streams?